# How to change register link of laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following Laravel code which gives me a `domain.com/register` link.

I want to change it `domain.com/register?ref=abc`

I tried adding `route('register') ?ref=abc` but it didn't work.

```
<a style="margin-bottom: 5px;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 600;" href="{{ route('login') }}" class=""><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log In</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="margin-bottom: 5px;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 600;" href="{{ route('register') }}" class=""><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Registration</a>
```

Comment: what 'not worked' ... what did you do, the actual code, what happened, what do you expect to happen; 'not worked' or 'doesnt work' etc, are not descriptions of problems

Comment: do like this `href="{{ route('register', ['ref' => 'abc']) }}"`

Comment: will it give this url ? domain.com/regiter?ref=abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to pass parameters to a url using `route()`, do it like this:

`route('routeName', ['param'=>'value'])`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route

Comment: if i want to use   $basic->reference_id instead of abc then?

Comment: `href="{{ route('routeName', ['ref'=> $basic->reference_id]) }}"`